# Python enum issue

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I've been working with a project were there are couple of Constants which i need to put and read it back.

So far the `Enum` seems works with small text and simple numbers.

Sample:

```
  class AppConstants(Enum):
     CLIENT_ID = "913940213390-k7ubu14.apps.example.com"
```

The above doesn't work as it contains hyphen. without the hyphen it works. The `dafjdl32323232-dfasfsaf` and `fdsfndsfsdfj-7687` doesn't work either.

So when I call `AppConstants.CLIENT_ID`, it stops with hyphen and cannot read the full value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does not work?

```
class AppConstants():   
    CLIENT_ID = "913940213390-k7ubu14.apps.example.com-somehyphens.letsbringmorehyphens-more-okay--34534-enough"
print(AppConstants.CLIENT_ID)
```

OUTPUT:

```
913940213390-k7ubu14.apps.example.com-somehyphens.letsbringmorehyphens-more-okay--34534-enough
```